# conio.h e time.h no cppdroid

Tags: android, c, header, biblioteca, compiladores

Tem como adicionar bibliotecas no cpp droid? Preciso usa essas duas bibliotecas  Mas o programa não identifica as funções. Caso nao haja como no cpp tem algum c compiller pra android que suporte?

Answer (score 1):

Conio.h pelo pouco que vi acho que ele é exclusividade do Windows (seu substituto é o ncurses, no Linux pelo menos) e você poderia mandar o que aparece exatamente no caso do time.h porquê penso que ele devia funcionar normalmente já que é da biblioteca padrão do C.

PS: Sou novo nesse negócio de programação, estou estudando por fora e em um curso de técnico de programação e pretendo fazer faculdade de ciências da computação após o ensino médio então desculpa se a resposta estiver muito errada.

Comment: tudo bem, vlw pela ajuda